# How does this code create a new record in MySQL without any insert statement?

Tags: java, mysql, insert

How does this source code create a new database record?  I am reverse engineering a java application, and I don't have much java experience myself.  I would expect to see something like "INSERT INTO ShipBargePipe (columns) VALUES (values) etc.  But All i see is a dbTransfers object and nothing else. Does anyone have any idea of how this works?

Thanks in advance.

`

```
  int insertSBP(String direction, int selectedTransferTypeNumber, int selectedSBPNumber, Timestamp shouldStart, int barrels, String notes)
    throws NumberFormatException, SQLException
  {
    int newTransferNumber = -1;
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
      int userNumber = GV.user.getUserNumber();

      conn = GV.getConnection(false);

      ResultSetCA selectedProducts = (ResultSetCA)this.jListProducts.getSelectedVectors();
      ResultSetCA selectedSources = null;
      ResultSetCA selectedDestinations = null;
      if (direction.equals("Outbound")) {
        selectedSources = (ResultSetCA)this.jListSourceTanks.getSelectedVectors();
      } else {
        selectedDestinations = (ResultSetCA)this.jListDestinationTanks
          .getSelectedVectors();
      }
      this.dbTransfers.resetChanged();

      this.dbTransfers.setInt(selectedTransferTypeNumber, "transferTypeNumber");
      this.dbTransfers.setInt(userNumber, "userNumber");
      this.dbTransfers.setTimeStamp(shouldStart, "ShouldStartStamp");
      this.dbTransfers.setInt(selectedSBPNumber, "SBPNumber");
      this.dbTransfers.setString(notes, "Notes");
      this.dbTransfers.setInt(barrels, "BarrelsRequested");
      this.dbTransfers.insert(conn);

      newTransferNumber = DbObject.lastId(conn);
      if (direction.equals("Outbound")) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < selectedSources.size(); counter++)
        {
          int tankNumber = selectedSources.getInt(counter, 0);
          int customerNumber = selectedSources.getInt(counter, 2);

          this.dbTransferTank.resetChanged();
          this.dbTransferTank.setInt(newTransferNumber, "transferNumber");
          this.dbTransferTank.setInt(tankNumber, "tankNumber");
          this.dbTransferTank.setString("s", "sourceDest");
          this.dbTransferTank.setInt(customerNumber, "customerNumber");
          this.dbTransferTank.setNull("startBarrels");
          this.dbTransferTank.insert(conn);
        }
      } else {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < selectedDestinations.size(); counter++)
        {
          int tankNumber = selectedDestinations.getInt(counter, 0);
          int customerNumber = selectedDestinations.getInt(counter, 2);

          this.dbTransferTank.resetChanged();
          this.dbTransferTank.setInt(newTransferNumber, "transferNumber");
          this.dbTransferTank.setInt(tankNumber, "tankNumber");
          this.dbTransferTank.setString("d", "sourceDest");
          this.dbTransferTank.setInt(customerNumber, "customerNumber");
          this.dbTransferTank.setNull("startBarrels");
          this.dbTransferTank.insert(conn);
        }
      }
      for (int counter = 0; counter < selectedProducts.size(); counter++)
      {
        int productNumber = selectedProducts.getInt(counter, 0);
        this.dbProductTransfer.resetChanged();
        this.dbProductTransfer.setInt(newTransferNumber, "transferNumber");
        this.dbProductTransfer.setInt(productNumber, "productNumber");
        this.dbProductTransfer.insert(conn);
      }
      conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.rollback();
      }
      throw e;
    }
    return newTransferNumber;
  }
```

`

Edit * Here is the dbObject insert method and it's depended createInsert method.

It looks like it dynamically loops through the columns to build the SQL query string.   Maybe there is a way to enable logging on the mysql database so i can see exactly what the query strings are ran against it?

`

```
  String createInsert()
    throws SQLException
  {
    String fieldNames = "";
    String values = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
      if (this.fields[i].isChanged()) {
        if (fieldNames.equals(""))
        {
          fieldNames = this.fields[i].getName();
          values = "?";
        }
        else
        {
          fieldNames = fieldNames + ", " + this.fields[i].getName();
          values = values + ",?";
        }
      }
    }
    if (this.fields.equals("")) {
      throw new SQLException("The table " + this.tableName + 
        " does not have anything to insert");
    }
    return createInsert(this.schema + "." + this.tableName, fieldNames, values);
  }
```

`

`

```
  public void insert(Connection conn)
    throws SQLException
  {
    Statement stmt = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    try
    {
      String dml = createInsert();
      printDebug(dml);
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(dml);
      for (i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
        if (this.fields[i].isChanged())
        {
          this.fields[i].setInPreparedStatement(ps, j);
          if (this.fields[i].getObject() == null) {
            printDebug(j + ": " + this.fields[i].getObject());
          } else {
            printDebug(j + ": '" + this.fields[i].getObject() + "'");
          }
          j++;
        }
      }
      int v = ps.executeUpdate();
      if (v != 1) {
        throw new SQLException("I can not insert the table " + this.tableName);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      resetChanged();
      if (ps != null) {
        ps.close();
      }
      if (stmt != null) {
        stmt.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

`

Edit*  After further digging, I enabled logging on mysql and it shows me exaclty what is going on behind the scenes when new records are added / deleted etc.

`

```
170426 15:39:16       4 Query       SET autocommit=0
              4 Prepare     [5] SELECT transfertypenumber, transfertypename, abbreviation FROM rc.transfertypes WHERE  transfertypename= ? 
              4 Execute     [5] SELECT transfertypenumber, transfertypename, abbreviation FROM rc.transfertypes WHERE  transfertypename= 'Tank'
              4 Prepare     [6] INSERT INTO rc.transfers(transfertypenumber, usernumber, shouldstartstamp, notes, barrelsrequested)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
              4 Execute     [6] INSERT INTO rc.transfers(transfertypenumber, usernumber, shouldstartstamp, notes, barrelsrequested)  VALUES (5,49,'2017-04-26 15:39:05','ZACKSCRIVEN',999)
              4 Prepare     [7] SELECT last_insert_id()
              4 Execute     [7] SELECT last_insert_id()
              4 Prepare     [8] INSERT INTO rc.transfertank(transfernumber, tanknumber, sourcedest, customernumber)  VALUES (?,?,?,?)
              4 Execute     [8] INSERT INTO rc.transfertank(transfernumber, tanknumber, sourcedest, customernumber)  VALUES (76265,1,'s',18)
              4 Prepare     [9] INSERT INTO rc.transfertank(transfernumber, tanknumber, sourcedest, customernumber)  VALUES (?,?,?,?)
              4 Execute     [9] INSERT INTO rc.transfertank(transfernumber, tanknumber, sourcedest, customernumber)  VALUES (76265,9,'d',18)
              4 Prepare     [10] INSERT INTO rc.producttransfer(transfernumber, productnumber)  VALUES (?,?)
              4 Execute     [10] INSERT INTO rc.producttransfer(transfernumber, productnumber)  VALUES (76265,21)
              4 Query       commit
```

`

Comment: I can see the `INSERT` statement; it is generated by this call: `this.dbTransfers.insert(conn);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbTransfers and dbTransferTank seem to represent some sort of ORM (object-relational mapping) object.  The insert statement isn't called directly by this code, but is embedded in the lines that call these objects' respective `.insert` method.

Comment: Thanks!  I looked deeper into it and that's definitely what it is doing. In theory makes it much easier when writing the code. except I am trying to reverse engineer it, and I don't have easy access to the query strings. Maybe there is a way to have MySQL log every query ran against it??

Comment: That *might* be a waste of time.  If you assume that everything that influences the insert happens between a call to ".resetChanged()" and a subsequent call to ".insert()", the lines in between tell you exact which columns are being updated.  The column name appears to be the last argument to these ".setInt", ".setNull", etc calls.

MySQL has a "slow log" feature, but you might get MUCH more of a log than you're looking for.

Comment: It seems to have gotten me what I am interested in.
See edit